# How to get the ID of a div when using bind() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following `div`.

```
<div id="123" class="abc">Foobar</div>
```

I know I can do this to trigger a function when this `div` is moused-over:

```
$(".abc").bind({
    mouseenter : SomeFunction(id)
});
```

With this, before `SomeFunction` runs, I want to be able to extract out the id of this `div`, which is "123", and pass it though as a parameter to `SomeFunction` for it to handle. Could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.abc').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    SomeFunction($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

---

Or, if you really want the event map syntax:

```
$('.abc').bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
        SomeFunction($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".abc").on({
   mouseenter : function() {
      var id = this.id;
       //or just
      SomeFunction(this.id);
   }
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".abc").bind('mouseenter', function() {
  var id = this.id;
})
```

according to you question

```
$(".abc").bind({

 mouseenter : function() {
                SomeFunction(this.id)
              }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".abc").bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.abc').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    SomeFunction(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass it to the function. There is a simple way.

```
$(".abc").bind({
    mouseenter : SomeFunction /* This might be a new way for you. 
                                 But its very useful sometimes */
});

function SomeFunction()
{
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); /* You can access $(this) in this function. 
                                    Here the $(this) will refer to the bound 
                                    element (i.e. of class ".abc") 
                                 */
}
```

Simple!

Comment: For whoever downvoted this http://jsfiddle.net/4WVgJ/ is a working example of it.